# Laravel: adding a second for each in JQuery results in just showing "undefined"

Tags: jquery, laravel, function, foreach, controller

I will first show all the necessary code for the for each in question (which is inside another for each that is currently working)

**Model:**

```
class HmsBbrGroupUser extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'hms_bbr_group_user';
}
```

**Table:**

[image: 1]

**Controller: (translated SQL query)**

```
use App\Models\HmsBbrGroupUser;

public function fetchgroupuser() {

    $all_group_users = HmsBbrGroupUser::selectRaw('hms_bbr_group_user.id,
                                                   hms_bbr_group_user.group_id,
                                                   hms_bbr_group_user.parent_id,
                                                   hms_bbr_group_user.jid,
                                                   hms_doctor.name ')
    ->leftJoin('hms_bbr_group', 'hms_bbr_group.id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_user.parent_id')
    ->leftJoin('hms_doctor', 'hms_doctor.jid', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_user.jid')
    ->where( 'hms_bbr_group_user.group_id', '=', 113)
    ->whereNull('hms_bbr_group.archived_by')
    ->get();

    return response()->json([
    'all_group_users'=>$all_group_users,
    ]);
}
```

**for each code:**

```
var tbody="";
$.each(response.all_groups, function (key, group) {
tbody+='<tr>'+
            '<td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">'+group.group_id+'</p>'+group.group_description+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+group.group_type_name+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+

            $.each(response.all_group_users, function (key, group_user) {
                '<p>'+group_user.jid+'</p>'
            });   
            tbody+='</td>'+

            '<td>'+getgroupstatus(group.effective_start_datetime, group.effective_end_datetime)+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.id+'" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> '+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.group_id+'" title="delete '+ group.group_name +'" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
});
```

Things to note:

- I translated the SQL Query on the screenshot above with proof that it is functioning to the laravel controller function.
- I am trying to add that function as a `for each` in my table shown below
- That `for each` inside another `for each` just shows `undefined`

[image: 2]

The code in question is:

```
$.each(response.all_group_users, function (key, group_user) {
  '<p>'+group_user.jid+'</p>'
  });   
tbody+='</td>'+
```

As show in my SQL query above: `all_group_users` has the appropriate output. I am wondering why this is shown as `undefined` when placing it inside the functioning `for each` of `all_groups`.

I hope this explanation is enough, feel free to tell if I need to elaborate any more. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it like this:

```
var tbody = "";
$.each(response.all_groups, function(key, group) {
  tbody += '<tr>' +
    '<td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">' + group.group_id + '</p>' + group.group_description + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + group.group_type_name + '</td>' +
    '<td>';

    $.each(response.all_group_users, function(key, group_user) {
      tbody += '<p>' + group_user.jid + '</p>'
    });
    tbody += '</td>' +

    '<td>' + getgroupstatus(group.effective_start_datetime, group.effective_end_datetime) + '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<button type="button" value="' + group.id + '" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> ' +
    '<button type="button" value="' + group.group_id + '" title="delete ' + group.group_name + '" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
});
```

This is the part i've changed:

```
'<td>';

$.each(response.all_group_users, function(key, group_user) {
  tbody += '<p>' + group_user.jid + '</p>'
});
tbody += '</td>' +
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick, though now I have a separate issue this time regarding using a completely different function on that .each inside the table. I will be posting this in a different question

Comment: @GetSomeHelp No problem, happy to help.